# populating first field in form with cursor

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I'm designing a series of forms. Is there a way I can mark a field to be populated by the browsers cursor (just like this pages loads with the cursor already in the title field above).

Thanks
Giles

Answer (score 4):

Use `focus()` function like this in Javascript. Put this code at the end of your HTML code, just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("textboxid").focus();

</script>
```

Replace the `textboxid` with the ID of the `<input>` text box you are using in your form.

Comment: Make sure this code goes *after* the textbox, not before, and that your textboad `id` is unique, of course.

Comment: The problem with this is that you clutter up your page with javascript functions(this won't be the only thing you want to do with javascript) and then you have to rewrite the function on every page where you want to autofocus a text field. Much better is to have the function in a separate file as described below

Answer (score 1):

In a HTML5 page, for browser supporting HTML5, you can do:

```
<input name="lorem" autofocus>
```

Vanilla Javascript:

```
<input id="lorem" name="lorem">
...
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("lorem").focus();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#email').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript to set your desired input focus:

**Using JavaScript:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("xtpo_1").focus();
</script>
```

**Using a JavaScript Library like Jquery:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#xtpo_1").focus();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Even better, write an function

```
function autoFocus(x){

 document.getElementById(x).focus();

}
```

and put it in a separate javascript file called basic_functions.js or something.

Load that file at the top of your page in the header like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="basic_functions.js"></script>
```

In your body tag, call the function onload.

```
<body onload="focus('first_name')" >
```

Then create you input:

```
<input type='text' value='' name='first_name' id='first_name' />
```

That way you keep javascript functions out of your page and you can reuse the function on other pages. you can then put other basic functions like this in that file and include it in all pages where it is needed

Comment: Does anyone know of a way to run a function 'onload' within the input tag?  <input type='text' onload="focus(this)" />

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it in jQuery style and paste js-code anywhere:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="name"><br />
<input type="text" id="email">
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#email').focus();
});
```

Check it online: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4d5JG/

Comment: I finally went with jQuery as it's so simple (and also because I want to get more practise of using it). V simple example above. Many thanks to all

Comment: I dont want to advertisize something, but there is awsome book, absolutly clear for novice: _jQuery: Novice to Ninja_: http://www.sitepoint.com/books/jquery1/

Comment: Also here is good practice to check solution so other Stackoverflowed people can see that it is solved problem.